# Why is this echoing Resource id #5 -Resource id #6?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 
$text = mysql_query("SELECT `Text` FROM `Banner` WHERE `ID`='1'");
$user = mysql_query("SELECT `User` FROM `Banner` WHERE `ID`='1'");
echo $text . " -" . $user; ?>
```

It's for a announcement box.

I'm gonna make an UPDATE `mysql_query` call to update it.

The database is set to:

```
ID - 1
Text - Welcome to PeopleHub! User - Thomas Doyle
```

Comment: just using mysql_query is not enough

Comment: what do I need to do?

Comment: $text = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `Text` FROM `Banner` WHERE `ID`='1'"));

Comment: Now, it says Array -Array.

Comment: Don't add "SOLVED" to the title. Instead, add an answer and accept it if you feel this question will be helpful to future visitors, otherwise delete the question. Also, you should include the applicable language tag in the question.